# Cannot set maximum duration for video recording?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift4

I have created a custom camera where I want to set the maximum recording time to 30 seconds. Here is where the code is written for setting max value.

```
@objc func videoAction(sender: UIButton){

    if(imageSetAction()){
        videoImage.image = UIImage(named: "video")
        flashButton.isHidden = true
        videoLabel.textColor = ConstantColors.selectedTextColor
        currentSelected = sender.tag
        if(videoButton.isEnabled){
            if(photoOutput != nil){
                captureSession.removeOutput(photoOutput!)
            }

            self.movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
            self.movieFileOutput?.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 30, preferredTimescale: 600)
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput!) {
                captureSession.addOutput(movieFileOutput!)
            }
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
        }
        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
        self.semiCircleView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture);
        videoButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

After the same I have an option for user to edit videos  SO I am calling default video editor in delegate method.

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    if error == nil {
        //UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
        if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath: outputFileURL.path){
            let videoEditorController = UIVideoEditorController()
            videoEditorController.delegate = self
            videoEditorController.videoPath = outputFileURL.path
            videoEditorController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            videoEditorController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            present(videoEditorController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    print("completed")
}

func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didStartRecordingTo fileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection]) {
    movieFileOutput?.maxRecordedDuration = CMTimeMake(30, 1)

    /* After 30 seconds, let's stop the recording process */
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30.0, execute: {
        debugPrint("longpress ended")
        self.movieFileOutput?.stopRecording()
        self.removeProgressBar()
    })
}
```

Don't know why but the video is only recording for 10 seconds. Any Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple documentation about maxRecordedDuration method.

> This property specifies a hard limit on the duration of recorded
>   files. Recording is stopped when the limit is reached and the
>   fileOutput(_:didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:) delegate method is
>   invoked with an appropriate error. The default value of this property
>   is invalid, which indicates no limit.

Maybe you shouldn't stop recording yourself if it'll be stopping in fileOutput(_:didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:) method.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate method will be called when maximumDuration is reached, but error will not be nil

func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?)